# What's the difference between these hash functions H, H1 and H2?

Tags: notation, hash-signature

These are hash functions, but I don't understand their notations, can anyone tell me what's the difference between H, H1 and H2?
$\mathbb{G}_1$ is an additive group and $\mathbb{G}_2$ is a multiplicative group. Both groups have the same prime order p and their bilinear mapping is $e: \mathbb{G}_1 \times \mathbb{G}_1 \to \mathbb{G}_2$
Source:[https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~misra/papers/T-ITS-2011.pdf](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/%7Emisra/papers/T-ITS-2011.pdf)

\begin{align}
H&:   \mathbb G_1\to\{0,1\}^n\\
H_1&:  \mathbb G_2\to\{0,1\}^n\\
H_2&:  \{0,1\}^n\times\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n
\end{align}

Comment: @kelalaka I edited now , thank u for telling me

Comment: It from an article , should i post it too ?

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: There is nothing special there. If you search the hash in the paper you will see that thy used SHA-1!

Comment: I know it's SHA-1, but what's the difference in using just one of them and why they have different notations?

Comment: Because the input domain is different...

Comment: I still don't get it , for me it seems that each hash function is defined differently and have different functionalities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $H:\mathbb G_1\to\{0,1\}^n$ means that $H$ takes as input an element of $\mathbb G_1$, and produces as output an $n$-bit bistring.

The notation $H_1:\mathbb G_2\to\{0,1\}^n$ similarly means that $H_1$ takes as input an element of $\mathbb G_2$, and produces as output an $n$-bit bistring.

The notation $H_2:\{0,1\}^n\times\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ means that $H_2$ takes as input a pair of $n$-bit bistrings, and produces as output an $n$-bit bistring.

If you ask me, the names are not well chosen. It would be more mnemonic to use $H_1$ (resp. $H_2$, $H$) where there's $H$ (resp $H_1$, $H_2$).

But that's far from the worse there is in this [paper](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/%7Emisra/papers/T-ITS-2011.pdf). Things like

> The ECDLP had been proved to be a hard problem [[19]](https://www.dima.unige.it/%7Emorafe/MaterialeCTC/p80-menezes.pdf).

are wrong (what's cited to support this falsehood actually makes ECDLP tractable on some curves). I hope studying this paper was not recommended as part of a course in cryptography. If so, I fear there's something deeply flawed in this recommendation process.

---

Addition per [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/189273): I do not see that the authors explain how they build their hashes, except for a mention of SHA-1 in section VI. A reasonable implementation with $n=160$ based on SHA-1 could use

$$\begin{align}
H(g)&\underset{\text{def}}=\operatorname{SHA-1}(c_0\mathbin\|\hat g)\\
H_1(g)&\underset{\text{def}}=\operatorname{SHA-1}(c_1\mathbin\|\hat g)\\
H_2(u,v)&\underset{\text{def}}=\operatorname{SHA-1}(c_2\mathbin\|u\mathbin\|v)\end{align}$$
where $\hat g$ is a bitstring uniquely representing (as a fixed number of bits) an element $g$ of $\mathbb G_1$ or $\mathbb G_2$, and $c_0$, $c_1$, $c_2$ are public distinct 32-bit bitstrings tasked with making the three hash functions somewhat independent from the perspective of security analysys.

Note: SHA-256 or better should be used rather than SHA-1, which is obsolete and [quite practically broken](https://shattered.io/) as a collision-resistant hash when operating on messages sizably larger than 768-bit. But as far as we know, SHA-1 remains 80-bit secure in the above constructions, because what's hashed is short.

Note: This shall not be construed as an endorsement of the article. I do not understand enough about functional requirements of a Pseudonymous Authentication-Based Conditional Privacy Protocol for VANETs to tell if they are met by the cryptography outlined; and only understand some of the crypto involved. The article does not tell enough to convince a cryptographer about the security of the implementation. In particular, I have doubt that the BLS signature based on "the Type-A curve defined in the PBC library with the default parameters" could be fast, 154-bit as suggested (the exact size is not stated), and secure to the 80-bit security level targeted.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, this paper wasn't recommended as part of a course in cryptography but I was given the task of searching for a Cryptographic solution for VANETs to implement. Honestly, I have no experience in cryptography and I don't know much so I can't tell if there are wrong things. I assumed that scientific articles are proved to be true.

Comment: @Chai Ma: cryptography articles in reputable peer-reviewed cryptographic journals can generally be trusted as mostly correct. For cryptography, that includes [IACR publications](https://www.iacr.org/publications/). Here the publication's theme is intelligent transportation systems. This is applied science, and not cryptography, thus it can't be blindly assumed that the material is correct from a cryptographic standpoint.

Comment: I see now, thank you for sharing that with me. I was wondering about something in this article, they're using the BLS short signature scheme the one proposed by Boneh et al and ECDLP, how can I implement these concepts? Is a trusted library for them that I should implement or something else?

Comment: BLS is hard to implement, especialy the choice of pairing. Here's a [list of libraries](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/f2d720010506569d3a39). I can't make a first-hand recommendation of any.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. How can $H_2$(which is a SHA1 hash function) take a pair of n-bit bistrings as input? I mean hash functions take only one parameter as input right?