# How to construct Hash function in python3?

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves

In many cryptographic protocols design like [this](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/12/10/1687/htm) one, I have seen the statement 'Choose a Hash function for example:
\begin{align}
h&:  \{0,1\}^*\times\mathbb G\to\mathbb Z_q^*\\
h_2&:  \{0,1\}^*\times\{0,1\}^*\times\mathbb G\to\mathbb Z_q^*\\
\end{align}
in which it takes as input a binary string and a random element of some group and outputs an element of multiplicative group of prime field. How could I construct such a hash function?

Comment: You have recently asked a [similar question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87012/555). And you have accepted an answer, which is supposed to tell that you are satisfied. You even [told so](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/190909)! At least, try to explain where your problem is: understanding the notation? Building the group G, or getting a representative?

Comment: Thank you for closing the question.
The other question's answer was satisfying in explaining the input of the hash function. What I mean now by the question is how the hashed value h can be in $\mathbb Z_q^*$ ?

Comment: I'll answer in your other question

Comment: You had many comments under the question, if nothing was clear or something missing you can comment that too.

Comment: @kelalaka thank you :)  but it's okay now I got the answer and everything is clear