# How to have a hash function that maps from a group element to a binary string of a certain size in charm-crypto?

Tags: encryption, hash, elliptic-curves, group-theory, pairings

I am facing a problem in programming with the [charm-crypto](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm) library. The hash functions for pairing group elements in charm-crypto can only map from a string to a specific field: $\mathbb Z_r$, $G_1$ or $G_2$.

Examples:
$$\begin{align}
H_1: \{0, 1\}^*\to\ &G_1\\
H_2: \{0, 1\}^*\to\ &Z_r\\
H_3: \{0, 1\}^*\to\ &G_2\\
\end{align}$$

I am implementing a certificateless public key encryption scheme with keyword search from [this research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330763346_A_provably_secure_certificateless_public_key_encryption_with_keyword_search). And in this algorithm in the global setup part I want a hash function as $H_4: G_2\to \{0, 1\}^n$ for some length $n$ i.e., mapping from group element to a binary string of length $n$. In this case the group $G_2$ consists of points on an elliptic curve.

Can someone please guide me how to implement the hash mapping $H4$ in charm-crypto? I would be grateful for any help in this regard.

Comment: I wonder why this kind of paper is circulation around. We had two question about this, let me search. [1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87012/18298) and [2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/86375/18298)

Comment: Thank you @kelalaka I will take a look at these.

Comment: Anything wrong with: if $r\in G_2$ we define $H_4(r)$ as $\operatorname{SHAKE256}(R,n)$ where $R$ is a unique representation of $r$ as bitstring, and $\operatorname{SHAKE256}$ as defined in [FIPS 202](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.202)?

Comment: @fgrieu Not sure if it will work. I will have to check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want a hash function as $H_4: G_2\to \{0, 1\}^n$ for some length $n$ i.e., mapping from group element to a binary string of length $n$. In this case the group $G_2$ consists of points on an elliptic curve.

If $r\in G_2$, we can define $H_4(r)$ as $\operatorname{SHAKE256}(R,n)$ where $R$ is a *unique* representation of $r$ as bitstring, and $\operatorname{SHAKE256}$ as defined in [FIPS 202](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.202).

One way to obtain $R$: if the point $r$ has Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ in field $\mathbb F_p$ with $p$ prime, $2^{8(\ell-1)}<p<2^{8\ell}$, $0\le x<p$, $0\le y<q$, then we can use $R=\operatorname{I2OSP}(x,\ell)\mathbin\|\operatorname{I2OSP}(y,\ell)$ where $\operatorname{I2OSP}$ is standard big-endian conversion to octet string (as used in e.g. [PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=8)). This can be adapted to other fields.

If $\operatorname{SHAKE256}$ is used to construct the other hashes $H_1$, $H_2$, $H_3$, it's prudent to prefix the input of $\operatorname{SHAKE256}$ with distinct constants.