# Recommendations for tools and libraries to aid implementation for a Private Key Generator

Tags: hash, pairings

I'm currently tasked to implement [this cryptographic scheme](http://scis.scichina.com/en/2019/032104.pdf). But currently struggle to understand these hash functions of the scheme. Can anyone explain and suggest a way or some kind of tool to build these hashes?

```
Two groups G1 and G2 of the same order p and a bilinear pairing e: G1 × G1 → G2.

Hash functions H1, H2: {0, 1}* → G1, h: G1 → Zp, and H: {0, 1}* → Zp.
```

Comment: article is paywalled

Comment: This might be a dupe of this one.[how to use these hash functions in python?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87012/18298) and this one [What's the difference between these hash functions H, H1 and H2?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/86375/18298)

Comment: "_implement this cryptographic scheme_" is hopelessly vague, given that the paywalled URL you reference does not describe the scheme. As stated, the question is without meaning. Please give it meaning by specifying what you intend to implement. The portion of the scheme currently quoted is not enough to implement the scheme, as the OP attests.

Comment: Updated the article's link and rephrased my question also. To be more precise, it's that I don't know how to build these kinds of hash functions.